How to UV Map correctly a lowpoly egg model?
Hey i'm trying to texture a egg model with a water texture, i tried every type of UV Mapping (such as "Unwrap", "Smart UV", "Cylinder" ecc.) but they all have the same problem that the texture appears discontinuous like in this screenshot of the Smart UV Project
"Project from view" looks good but

but stretches because obviously is projected just the part from the view
Someone more expert than me knows how to fix it? Thanks for your help :)

Seams are some of the tricky ones to fix, most people try to reduce the seams at minimum, other try to hide it from the camera view and some people would rather hand paint to get everything correctly (time consuming, but very effective). I prefer this last method to deal with seams... You could try to move that section on the UV map until you find the closest to the one below to make it look like it's seamless, although it's not gonna be 100% accurate

You could do it procedurally.
If you want to keep the image, you could edit your image texture so that it's repeatable (if it's not already), create a very small circle at the top and bottom with a bevel on vertex operation, unwrap them, unwrap the rest with the Sphere Projection option:


Thanks, i'm gonna try that and let you know!

We can't do nothing also about the strechment that occurs on the top and on the bottom?

you can move down the top edge loop in the UV Editor in order to unstretch but the lines will always points towards the pole
